# Is my pineapple plant healthy?

Tags: plant-health, fruit-trees, citrus, pineapple

[image]Our pineapple plant started to lose its color so we repotted it in a larger pot and added the recommended soil and fertilizer. We trimmed the leaves that were browned/yellowing at the end as well. It’s been a few days and the color does not seem to have come back yet. Does anyone have any recommendations for us or know if the pineapple looks healthy?

Comment: Careful not to overwater